# How to print the props value in console.log?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to react I was working on simple project as my code is below
I just noticed how to print the value of  listItem={people} as it is passed as props
in my list component i.e <List listItem={people} so I can understand it in better way that
what I am getting in listItem here, I tried {console.log(listItem)} but it says undefined

```
    *react*
   function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data);


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h3>{people.length} birthdays today</h3>
      <List listItem={people} />
      
      <button onClick={() => setPeople([])}>Clear All</button>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: console.log(props.listItem) in `List` component, please refer to react docs

Answer (score 1):

All the parameters that you add to a component, in the component function will be sent as an object which has as key the parameter name you choose and the value that you set to it.

In the case below, I am destructuring the object that the List Component gets as a parameter.

```
function List({ listItem }) {
  console.log(listItem)
  
  return <div>List Component</div>
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you can find more about destructuring.

Comment: Yeah I know that how to Destructuring them once it has been received as props but I was curios about Is there any way to print just below the <List listItem={people}/> as
{console.log(people)} prints the people but when I am trying to print {console.log(listItem)  it gives me error idk why

Comment: As you do `{console.log(people)}` in App Component, you can do `{console.log(listIem)}` in List Component, you can't use listItem in App, but I don't understand why you can't log the people variable and you want it to be named exactly listItem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the prop first, this can be done with the following code.

```js
console.log(props.listItem)
```

Please refer to the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)